# What are all the Accolades?

Tags: armello

After winning a game, I saw that each player was accorded different accolades. "Warlock" and "Goldfinger" I figure refer to spellcasting and gold acquired respectively, but I'm a bit confused as to what "Wanderer" could mean (maybe number of tiles traveled?). What are all the Accolades possible and what are the requirements needed to get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accolades are:

> Assassin - Most trickery kills
>
> Collector - Equipped three or more treasures
>
> Conqueror - Most settlements captured
>
> Corruptor - Most rot given to others
>
> Destroyer - Most heroes killed in combat
>
> Diplomat - Cooperative cards played more than twice
>
> Goldfinger - Most gold earned
>
> Harbinger - Most rot gained
>
> Healer - Most wounds healed
>
> Infamous - Most kings guards killed in combat
>
> Landlord - More than 4 settlements held at any point
>
> Lone Wolf - Finished a game vs. 3 friends.
>
> Martyr - Most deaths
>
> Necromancer - Most rot gained from spells
>
> Shadow - Most AP spent in stealth
>
> Socialite - Equipped three or more followers
>
> Sorcerer - Most spell perils played
>
> Strategist - Most trickery perils played
>
> Thrifty - Least gold spent
>
> Underdog - Won despite being several ranks lower than opponents
>
> Vanquisher - Most banes killed in combat
>
> Wanderer - Most tiles walked across
>
> Warlock - Most spell kills

According to a steam post, "*For the above, in case of ties player 1 has priority, then player 2, then player 3.*"

> Immortal - Zero deaths
>
> Pacifist - No hero kills
>
> Pariah - No spells cast
>
> Purist - No trickery cards played
>
> Journeyman - All quests completed

And again, according to a steam post, "*For these 5 above if there is a tie, it's resolved randomly.*"

And finally, "*If after awarding the above there are players that have no accolades, they are awarded the following*"

> Squire - No accolades

And another relevant note from the steam post, "*After that if a player has more than 4, 4 of them are chosen randomly.*"

[Source 1](http://armello.wikia.com/wiki/Accolades)

[Source 2](https://steamcommunity.com/app/290340/discussions/0/523897023723454462/)